# Filter & sort multidimensional array with multiple values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, filtering

I have a large multidimensional array something like the below:

```
Array( 
    [1] => Array ( [type] => blah1 [category] => cat1 [exp_range] => this_week ) 
    [2] => Array ( [type] => blah1 [category] => cat2 [exp_range] => next week ) 
    [3] => Array ( [type] => blah1 [category] => cat1 [exp_range] => next week ) 
    [4] => Array ( [type] => blah2 [category] => cat2 [exp_range] => this_week )
)
```

I want to be able to filter this array with multiple filters.
eg.  filtering where category = cat1  and type = blah1 would return array 1 and 3.

I have the below function that would return keys 1,2,3 which is incorrect as array 2 doesnt have both **cat1**  and **blah1**

Can anyone see what I need to do to get this working?

Also would it be possible to incorporate sortin in this function, if so how?

```
function array_searcher($needles, $array) { 
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
           foreach ($value as $v) { 
            if ($v == $needle) { 
                $keys[] = $key; 
            } 
           }
        }
    }
    return $keys;
}
```

Comment: It seems like this would be better modeled as a single array of objects.

Comment: You may also want to see this thread the accepted answer is quite simple :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I decided to rewrite my answer to accommodate both filtering and sorting. I took a heavily object oriented approach to solving this problem, which I will detail below.*

You can see all of this code in action at this [**ideone.com live demonstration**](http://ideone.com/U8LjPv).

---

The first thing I did was **define two interfaces.**

```
interface Filter {
    public function filter($item);
}

interface Comparator {
    public function compare($a, $b);
}
```

As their names suggest, `Filter` is used for filtering, and `Comparator` is used for comparing.

Next, I **defined three concrete classes that implements these interfaces**, and accomplish what I wanted.

First is `KeyComparator`. This class simply compares the key of one element to the key of another element.

```
class KeyComparator implements Comparator {
    protected $direction;
    protected $transform;
    protected $key;

    public function __construct($key, $direction = SortDirection::Ascending, $transform = null) {
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->direction = $direction;
        $this->transform = $transform;
    }

    public function compare($a, $b) {
        $a = $a[$this->key];
        $b = $b[$this->key];

        if ($this->transform) {
            $a = $this->transform($a);
            $b = $this->transform($b);
        }

        return $a === $b ? 0 : (($a > $b ? 1 : -1) * $this->direction);
    }
}
```

You can specify a sort direction, as well as a transformation to be done to each element before they are compared. I defined a helped class to encapsulate my `SortDirection` values.

```
class SortDirection {
    const Ascending = 1;
    const Descending = -1;
}
```

Next, I defined `MultipleKeyComparator` which takes multiple `KeyComparator` instances, and uses them to compare two arrays against each other. The order in which they are added to the `MultipleKeyComparator` is the order of precedence.

```
class MultipleKeyComparator implements Comparator {
    protected $keys;

    public function __construct($keys) {
        $this->keys = $keys;
    }

    public function compare($a, $b) {
        $result = 0;

        foreach ($this->keys as $comparator) {
            if ($comparator instanceof KeyComparator) {
                $result = $comparator->compare($a, $b);

                if ($result !== 0) return $result;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Finally, I created `MultipleKeyValueFilter` which is meant to filter an array based on an array of key/value pairs:

```
class MultipleKeyValueFilter implements Filter {
    protected $kvPairs;

    public function __construct($kvPairs) {
        $this->kvPairs = $kvPairs;
    }

    public function filter($item) {
        $result = true;

        foreach ($this->kvPairs as $key => $value) {
            if ($item[$key] !== $value)
                $result &= false;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

---

Now, given the input array (*Notice I rearranged them a bit to make the sorting obvious*):

```
$array = array (
    '1' => array ('type' => 'blah2', 'category' => 'cat2', 'exp_range' => 'this_week' ),
    '2' => array ('type' => 'blah1', 'category' => 'cat1', 'exp_range' => 'this_week' ),
    '3' => array ('type' => 'blah1', 'category' => 'cat2', 'exp_range' => 'next_week' ),
    '4' => array ('type' => 'blah1', 'category' => 'cat1', 'exp_range' => 'next_week' )
);
```

Sorting can be achieved by doing the following:

```
$comparator = new MultipleKeyComparator(array(
    new KeyComparator('type'),
    new KeyComparator('exp_range')
));

usort($array, array($comparator, 'compare'));

echo "Sorted by multiple fields\n";
print_r($array);
```

Filtering can be achieved by doing the following:

```
$filter = new MultipleKeyValueFilter(array(
    'type' => 'blah1'
));

echo "Filtered by multiple fields\n";
print_r(array_filter($array, array($filter, 'filter')));
```

---

At this point I've given you a great deal of code. I'd suggest that your next step is to combine these two pieces into a single class. This single class would then apply both filtering and sorting together.

Comment: u really thinks that is "ridiculous reason"? Using `global` in this case? Or using `global` in general? No offense, but u have repu. over 5K , and advise use `global`.

Comment: I never use `global` in PHP. I dont advise anybody use it.

Comment: "options if you are on < PHP 5.3"... now 2014 :)

Comment: In >=5.3 added `goto`...It's about "it wouldn't be part of the language."

Comment: @voodoo417 Since you challenged me, I rewrote the whole thing to be super expansive and object oriented. It'll work in PHP 5+ and doesn't use globals. Doesn't get much better than that. Hope you're satisfied. ;)

Comment: "Hope you're satisfied"  )))))

Comment: well. being challenged seems... pretty constructive :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay with the response but this works great. Thanks so much for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

Do it:

```
$arr =  array(
  1 => array ( "type" => "blah1", "category" => "cat1", "exp_range" => "this_week" ),
  2 => array ( "type" => "blah1", "category" => "cat2", "exp_range" => "next week" ),
  3 => array ( "type" => "blah1", "category" => "cat1", "exp_range" => "this_week" ),
  4 => array ( "type" => "blah2", "category" => "cat2","exp_range" => "next week" ),
);

function filter(array $arr,array $params){
  $out = array();
  foreach($arr as $key=>$item){
     $diff = array_diff_assoc($item,$params);

     if (count($diff)==1) // if count diff == 1 - Ok
        $out[$key] = $item;
 }
 return $out;
}

$out = filter($arr,array("type" => "blah1", "category" => "cat1"));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
echo '</pre>';

// output

Array
(
  [1] => Array
     (
        [type] => blah1
        [category] => cat1
        [exp_range] => this_week
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [type] => blah1
        [category] => cat1
        [exp_range] => this_week
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the fact that your function will return the key of every array that contains "cat1" or "blah1". You can fix it with array_unique():

```
function array_searcher($needles, $array) { 
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
           foreach ($value as $v) { 
            if ($v == $needle) { 
                $keys[] = $key; 
            } 
           }
        }
    }
    return $keys;
}

$bigarray = array(
array('type' => 'blah1', 'category' => 'cat1', 'exp_range' => 'this_week'),
array('type' => 'blah1', 'category' => 'cat2', 'exp_range' => 'next week'),
array('type' => 'blah1', 'category' => 'cat1', 'exp_range' => 'next week'),
array('type' => 'blah2', 'category' => 'cat2', 'exp_range' => 'this_week')
);

$result = array_searcher(array('cat1','blah1'), $bigarray);
$unique_result = array_unique($result);
print_r($unique_result);
```

Answer (score 1):

so lets assign your base array to a variable:

```
$array = Array( 
[1] => Array ( [type] => blah1 [category] => cat1 [exp_range] => this_week ) 
[2] => Array ( [type] => blah1 [category] => cat2 [exp_range] => next week ) 
[3] => Array ( [type] => blah1 [category] => cat1 [exp_range] => next week ) 
[4] => Array ( [type] => blah2 [category] => cat2 [exp_range] => this_week )
)
```

and lets's have an array containing our filter:

```
$filter = array(
'type' => 'blah1'
'category' => 'cat1'
)
```

then we start our filtering script

```
foreach ($array as $key => $row){
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($filter as $filterKey => $filterValue){
    if ($row[$filterKey] != $filterValue){
      $i++;
    }}
  if ($i == 0){
    $filteredArray[] = $row;
}}
```

if $i still equals 0 after the row is tested against our filter, we add the row to our filtered array

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember implementing this type of functionality many years ago:

http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?t=47855

Look to the sortRows() and _quickSort() methods

HTH