# PHP nested functions use a variable of the outer one in the inner one

Tags: php, function, closures, scope, nested-function

I want to sort bidimensional associative arrays by a given key, using `uasort`.

I have tried

```
function sortBy(&$arr, $key) {
    $cmp = function($a, $b) {
        global $key;
        return $a[$key] < $b[$key] ? -1 :
               $a[$key] == $b[$key] ? 0 : 1;
    };
    return uasort($arr, $cmp);
}
```

But `$key` is undefined inside `$cmp`.

Comment: You can do `function (args) use (variables)`. Another option is to get [object oriented as I answered at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319729/filter-sort-multidimensional-array-with-multiple-values/21320066#21320066).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this

```
function sortBy(&$arr, $key) {
    $cmp = function($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return $a[$key] < $b[$key] ? -1 :
           $a[$key] == $b[$key] ? 0 : 1;
    };
    return uasort($arr, $cmp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should solve the problem

```
function sortBy(&$arr, $key) {
    $cmp = function($a, $b) use($key) {
        global $key;
        return $a[$key] < $b[$key] ? -1 :
               $a[$key] == $b[$key] ? 0 : 1;
    };
    return uasort($arr, $cmp);
}
```

Notice that I added `use($key)` into the declaration of the nested function. You can find out more here http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php